# The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols Error

Tags: python, socket.io, raspberry-pi, flask-socketio

I'm trying to run a client an server in python using flask_socketio, socketIO_client and SOCKET.IO in a raspberry pi 4 but I'm getting the following error:

```
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
192.168.1.80 - - [05/Feb/2021 18:30:41] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NTpTT-L HTTP/1.1" 400 219 0.000618
```

These are my current versions:

pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/EDAdataLogger $ npm list socket.io
EDAdataLogger@ /home/pi/Desktop/EDAdataLogger
└── socket.io@3.1.1

pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/EDAdataLogger $ npm list socket.io-client
EDAdataLogger@ /home/pi/Desktop/EDAdataLogger
└── socket.io-client@3.1.1

```
python-engineio==4.0.0
python-socketio==5.0.4
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Session==0.3.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.0.1
```

How can I define JavaScript Socket.IO version and Socket.IO protocol revision so everything matches according to (https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/) ?

How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: The connection URL suggests your Socket.IO client is a version 1 or version 2. It should be a version 3 to be compatible with the Python packages that you installed. If you want the details versions 1 and 2 send `EIO=3` in the URL, while version 3 sends `EIO=4`.

Comment: Have you figured it out now??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There appears to be some [backward compatibility issues](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/578) with SocketIO. You can uninstall `python-engineio`, `python-socketio` (and `Flask-SocketIO` just to be on the safe side) and reinstall lower versions.

The combination that worked for me was:

```
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1
python-engineio==3.13.2
python-socketio==4.6.0
```

Comment: Which flask version would this be compatible with?

Answer (score 23):

To fix the version incompatibility, you can run below "upgrade"commands:

> ```
> pip install --upgrade python-socketio==4.6.0
>
> pip install --upgrade python-engineio==3.13.2
>
> pip install --upgrade Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1
> ```

Comment: Thank you Ravi! Worked perfectly to fix my issue on a M1 Mac!

Answer (score 3):

flask-socketio-5.1.2
python-engineio-4.3.2
python-socketio-5.6.0

script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.0/socket.io.js">

This worked for me. This error is due to dependency related to python-engineio .
After this, check your socket request shows EIO4 like this
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=mJ1g8wm0didssJSiAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200

Answer (score 2):

Check for the compatibility between the JS Client version and the Socket.IO server version here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/ and accordingly upgrade/downgrade the client/server version.

You will need these modules on the server side: 
Flask-SocketIO 
python-engineio 
python-socketio

You will have this kind of URL in your client:
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/

One working example, which I'm using:

**On Server side**: 
Flask-SocketIO==5.2.0 
python-engineio==4.3.3 
python-socketio==5.7.1 
simple-websocket==0.7.0

**On Client side**: 
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.js

Answer (score 2):

You are using The JavaScript client version 1.4.8, from about 6 years ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client/v/1.4.8.

I strongly recommend that you upgrade your Socket.IO client to the latest 4.x versions, but if that cannot be helped, then the [Flask-SocketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#version-compatibility) clearly tells you what versions of the Python packages to use:

[image: Socket.IO version compatibility table]

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.

The method you gave me was done beforehand

Even though java socketio ran with a version that was released five days ago,

The same problem has occurred

Once again, I will test it after installing the package to match the java socket 1.x version

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to use the socket.io version, not cloudflare as the source

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

my fix was to use socket io itself as source not cloudfare
`<script>src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"</script>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).