# The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols

Tags: python, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I am currently trying to connect server and client with flask_socketio, python-engineio and python-socketio. However, I'm getting the following error and I tried many solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069215/the-client-is-using-an-unsupported-version-of-the-socket-io-or-engine-io-protoco) but it still doesn't work

On the server:

`The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)`

On the client:

`WARNING:socketIO-client:127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io [engine.io waiting for connection] unexpected status code (400 "The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols")`

My currently config:

`python-engineio==4.3.3 python-socketio==5.7.1 Flask-SocketIO==5.2.0`

How can I fix this? Thank you guys

Comment: You have not indicated what version are you using for the client, which is the most important detail, since the error is about the client using a version that is unsupported by the server.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg I used the same version for both clients and server

Comment: What client are you using? The error message does not look like it is coming from a Python based client. If you are not using a Python client, then your claim that "it is the same version" cannot be accurate, since version numbering schemes are completely different across different implementations of the protocol.